# Discount code for cart as simple as possible?

Tags: php, forms, input, cart, discount

We need a really simple way to offer a discount code box in our cart. The shop is not a huge e-commerce solution, but a simple php-cart system.

Our idea is to have a box/input that validates when the correct code is entered and then recalculates a discount on the total price.

```
<input type='text' name='secret_code' class='textfield' value='' /> 
<input type='submit' name='update_voucher' value='Validate Code' />
```

We need a variable to store valid codes (one is sufficient).

The cart is like this:

```
<form method='post' action='$checkout'>
</form>
```

We have once built a proper contact form validation, but it's been long ago.

The cart is based on http://conceptlogic.com/jcart/

Thank you!

Comment: Impossable to help without knowing how the cart works

Comment: What is your actual question here? You suggested a solution, so we assume you tried to implement it. At what point did you run into a problem? Please post your code so far so that we can help with it. Without that we could only reply with meaningless attitudes.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Can understand that this all too vague!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is a simple form and if statement. $price would be the price that you set. Seeing you have not given details to your system the below code should help you get the idea of a solution.

Form (Place where you want user to input code):

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">                         
<input id="code" type="text" name="code" id="code">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>
```

PHP (Goes at top of checkout page):

```
if(count($_POST)>0) {
    if($_POST['code'] == "CouponCode"){
    $price - 20;
    }
}
```

Very basic but hope it helps.

Comment: Why use count when perhaps you could simply check if code is set? Seems like you don't need two if statements.

Comment: @Elevant that is true. You could do that. However the code works. As the saying goes: If it aint broke dont fix it.

Comment: Thanks! It helped narrow it down.

Comment: @plbr No Worries! Glad I Helped!